# How do you know what parameters/arguments to put in a closure?

Tags: php, function, closures

When do closures have parameters (or how do closures with parameters work)? I know that `use()` is used to *import* variables outside the anonymous function, but what about the parameter(s) of the closure itself?

Comment: You certainly get your money out of the word *use*. `;)`

Comment: @JaredFarrish The `use` is for import variable to the scope of anonymous function. Someting like `$fuc = function ($a, $b) use ($c) {}` .

Comment: Note, the link (as @xdazz points out above) was incorrect; reference [Anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of closures with parameters is currying:

```
function greeter($greeting)
{
  return function($whom) use ($greeting) {
    // greeting is the closed over variable
    return "$greeting $whom";
  };
}

$hello_greeter = greeter('hello');

echo $hello_greeter('world'); // will print 'hello world';
```

The `greeter` function will return a "half-implemented" function that will always start with the same greeting, followed by whatever is passed into it (e.g. the person to greet).

Comment: @JaredFarrish okay, it's not much different though :)

Comment: @JaredFarrish I don't see them though

Comment: That's because I fixed them. There's a missing `;` on the `return` and you already fixed the missing `$` on the function call.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I see ... well, thank you :) morphing code from JS to PHP is easy to mess up

Comment: @JackSpairow gah, i should have just started over in PHP =X

Comment: @JackSpairow - See the edit, there was a missing `;` on the end of the first `return`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a function that accept an anonymous function as parameter, then check the doc of the function.

If the function is written by you, then you are the controller, you decide it.

Comment: I'm much more familiar with Javascript closures, but to address the "why or when do you have arguments in a closure?", I would say when you are either matching an incoming signature (like in a handler), or it is more convenient or useful to pass as arguments. Comments?

Comment: @JaredFarrish PHP's closure is a litter different with javascript. When you use the variable outside, you need to use `use`.

Comment: Yes, I reading the Manual's [Using namespaces: Aliasing/Importing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) and I'm realizing I need to read up on this. Not the same as Javascript, for sure.

Comment: @JaredFarrish The `use` mentioned here is nothing relative with the namespaces.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Read here: the Example #3 http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Do you have a link to a Man page that explains in the context of the question? Note, I've never (had the opportunity) to use closures in PHP, so this is a bit new to me, too. EDIT: Oop, just saw your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Closures passed to PHP functions that should have parameters are detailed in the docs. A good example of this is [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php), which is used to apply the callback to an iterable:

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c');
array_walk($arr, function($key, $val) {
    echo $key . ' => ' . $val . "\n";
});
```

In the docs, the parameters that you should include on the callable passed to `array_walk()` are detailed under "Parameters." It says:

> Typically, funcname takes on two parameters. The array parameter's value being the first, and the key/index second.

Often times you will find similar hints on other functions in the PHP docs. I was disappointed  that the documentation for `array_map()` was not as detailed, but I can remember there being other functions that excepted callables that had sufficient closure parameter documentation.

---

If you are looking to write your own function that accepts closures (or other values that you can call) and dictates what parameters it must have, you can use the typehint `callback` in PHP 5.3 or `callable` in PHP 5.4.

```
function gobblesUpCallable(callable $func) {
    call_user_func($func); // Use this, someone could pass in a callable string or array
}
```

However, to specify parameters, you'll need to use `ReflectionClass` or `ReflectionFunction` which means you probably forgo `call_user_func()`.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a closure though, it doesn't close over anything; rather, it's an anonymous function .. then again, the term "closure" in PHP is ambiguous :)

Comment: @PhpMyCoder `Only variables can be passed by reference`

Comment: @Jack - Referencing the Manual for [anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), the first example is identical to the one here, except it uses a different function. What is wrong with the example?

Comment: the callback should've been the second parameter, thank you guys.

Comment: @JackSpairow Initially I was going to use `array_map()`, but then when I noticed how sparse the docs were for the callable I switched to `array_walk()` but forgot to swap the parameters. Good catch!

Answer (score 2):

`use()` is especially useful for functions that require a function as a parameter.  It might be required that the passed function take only two parameters and that any extra parameter is simply ignored.  In this case, use `use()` to "import" a variable from current scope to the anon function.

```
$myvar = 10;
$fun = function(&$val, $index) use ($myvar) {$val += $myvar;};
$testArray = array(1,2,3);
array_walk($testArray, $fun);
var_dump($testArray); // 11, 12, 13
```

Note: if your anon function signature was `function(&$val, $index, $myvar)` instead, you would get constant `warnings` when using your anon function with `array_walk` because that extra 3rd parameter is unused and undefined.  So, use `use()` to pass in that extra parameter instead.

Edit: you can also pass in variables by reference in `use()`...

```
$myvar = 10;
$fun = function(&$val, $index) use (&$myvar) {$myvar = 1; $val += $myvar;};
$testArray = array(1,2,3);
array_walk($testArray, $fun);
var_dump($testArray); // 2, 3, 4
echo $myvar; // 1
```