# Pass content rather than variables to PHP function

Tags: php, function, foreach

Is it possible to pass content that are not variables to a PHP function such as a loop or similar construct to be executed in the other function.

Here is a php version of how it can be done in javascript.

```
function myFunction($content){

    // something important that needs to be done before content

    $content

    // something important that needs to be done after content

}

myFunction({

    foreach($things_we_have as $key => $val){
        // Things to do in centre of the function
    }

});
```

Obviously that does not work. Can this be done and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Closures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php)/[anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) as the parameter of the function.

Example:

```
function myFunction($closure)
{

    // something important that needs to be done before content

    $closure($thingsWeHave);

    // something important that needs to be done after content

}

myFunction(function($thingsWeHave)
{
    foreach($thingsWeHave as $key => $val){
        // Things to do in center of the function
    }
});
```

Other examples are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-what-is-a-closure-and-why-does-it-use-the-use-identifier) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942560/how-do-you-know-what-parameters-arguments-to-put-in-a-closure)

Comment: I'm an idiot. Would have needed to do that in JS as well. Forgot about the need to declare that it was a function inside the ()